# navsat_transform_node: Tf has two or more unconnected trees

Tags: ekf, gps, navsat-transform-node, navsat-transform, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm new in ROS

I use robot_localisation Package for Fusing imu, gps, odometry
but i have problem with navsat_transform_node

when i launch the launch file i receive this warning:

[ WARN] [1492703521.573344934, 1492523889.516523566]: Could not obtain transform from imu0 to base_link. Error was Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'imu0' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.

the topic odometry/gps
is empty no message are publish

I don’t understood how i can fix

launch file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/anjvbz7n5w6eqa0/ekf_filter.launch?dl=0

Bag:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lwmhr3abc2e67s/u5-fuori10hzlungocoperto.bag?dl=0

Tanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259756/navsat_transform_node:-tf-has-two-or-more-unconnected-trees./) by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I took a look at your bag and launch files. It is true that the `navsat_transform` node is not publishing any messages to `/odometry/gps`, even though it is getting input data. One possible cause is the error in your task tree that is being reported: the transform from `imu0` to `base_link` is unknown. You have a static_transform_publisher for this in your launch file on line 10, but you have the frames around the wrong way, which means that it is saying that `base_link` is a child of `imu0`. Swap the frames on this line.

To fix the problem with `nmea_navsat_driver` prefixing its task frame with a slash, you need to use a version of the driver with the change specified in [this pull request](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/pull/33) applied.

Until that change is applied you will need to patch the driver yourself, which requires adding a local copy of it to your workspace to override the version installed with ROS.

In your workspace's `src` directory, clone a copy of the driver's source:

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver.git
```

[Here is the patch that will stop it adding the slash.](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/pull/33.diff) Save that file as `no_to_slashes.patch`, go to `<your workspace>/src/nmea_navsat_driver`, and then run the following command (modifying the path to `no_to_slashes.patch` as necessary):

```
patch -p1 < no_to_slashes.patch
```

(The `-p1` strips the first directory from the paths specified in the path file, in this case `a/` and `b/`; without this the patch command won't be able to find the file to modify.)

Then you should be able to compile your workspace and when you use the `nmea_navsat_driver` it will use your local, patched copy.

Once that pull request goes through, you will not need your modified version of the driver any more. But until a release is made of the fixed version you will still need to keep a copy of the driver source (cloned from Github without modifications) in your workspace so that the fixed version overrides the broken version installed using apt.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-21**:
i have this:

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-21**:
but i receive this warning:
Could not obtain transform from imu0 to base_link. Error was Could not find a connection between 'base_link' and 'imu0' because they are not part of the same tree.Tf has two or more unconnected trees.

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-21**:
You're right, you do. Sorry, I missed that in your launch file. Anyway, the problem there is that you have the frames around the wrong way. You are telling tf that `base_link` is a child of `imu0`. Try swapping the frames.

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-26**:
tank you, but now i have this warn:

[ WARN] : Could not obtain transform from /gps to base_link. Error was Invalid argument "/gps" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like

i try to add a node for transformation but not working

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-26**:
In tf2, frames are no longer allowed to start with a slash. I looked in your bag file and some of your topics are using the frame `/gps`. What published the `/fix0`, `/fix1` and `/vel` topics when you recorded your bag file?

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-27**:
**/fix0** and **/fix1** are message from two different GPS for **/vel** I ask and I let you know
Thanks

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2017-04-27**:
OK, you need to check what the frames for those are set to in their driving nodes. If the frame starts with a slash, remove the slash. The same goes for whatever is publishing `/vel`.

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-27**:
for gps i use this node:
rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 fix:=fix0 __name:=gps0
rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyACM1 fix:=fix1 __name:=gps1

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-27**:
this is the problem i opened:  https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/issues/35

for name_navsat_driver.

and for the /vel is publishing from the gps node

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-27**:
I noticed this other issues for the same problem:

https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/issues/31

https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/issues/24

https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/pull/33

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-29**:
Tanks for all your replay
Next week i can try on the robot but in the meantime i try to remove the **/**.
I found this http://wiki.ros.org/bag_tools

i run this command

rosrun bag_tools change_frame_id.py -o prova.bag -i u5-fuori10hzlungocoperto.bag -f gps -t /fix0 /fix1 /vel

and it works!

**Comment by [Pietro](https://answers.ros.org/users/30098/pietro/) on 2017-04-29**:
with new bag is going better but i receive this error:
Could not obtain transform from odom->base_link

i add a transformation for odom to base_link? with tf2_ros and with what parameters?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9tdui3l768tc2i/prova.bag?dl=0